# Why does IE11 try to load the site's root on its own?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, prefetch

Here's what happens when IE11 loads the login page of our site:

[image]

Basically, after loading the page, it tries to load `/`, and it's redirected to the login page again. I don't know when it starts and why, as there's nothing on the "Initiator" field.

I guess it's some sort of speculative prefetching that starts once the page is loaded. All I want to know, other than the reason, if there's a way to disable or prevent this behaviour, as it screws our redirection dynamics.

Comment: Without a repro URL, it will be difficult to troubleshoot what is wrong here. Most likely, you have an object with an empty `SRC` property.

Comment: @EricLaw I'll answer briefly for now, I'm in a hurry: if that's the case, it should have an initiator. It doesn't happen in IE10, or in Chrome or Firefox. It looks like a IE11 thing.

Comment: Without more information, no one is likely to be able to help.